# Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 255), stderr: Checking Dart SDK version... was unexpected at this time

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed flutter and set paths and developed apps for a while.  Suddenly this error occurred.

```
Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 255), stderr: Checking Dart SDK version... was unexpected at this time.
```

Even flutter doctor command gives the following error.

```
<< was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Hey did you resolved this issue. I am also getting the same